# using an if statement to choose type to declare a variable C++

Tags: c++

I am referencing a variable for use in a function and there are times it might be an int and times it might be a float. I have figured out a way to automatically tell which type I want the variable to be (either an int or a float) but I want a way to declare that variable so that when it is referenced later it will be the correct type. I know that you can cast one type of variable into another but it seems that it requires a new variable to be introduced.

Any thoughts?

Comment: what condition of if statement ?

Comment: [`boost::variant<int, float>`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/doc/html/variant.html)

Answer (score 3):

This is what [union](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Union_%28computer_science%29#C.2FC.2B.2B)s are for. Here is an example:

```
union int_or_float
{
    int i;
    float f;
};
```

And in your function:

```
void function(int_or_float param, bool is_int)
{
    if (is_int)
        do_something_with_int(param.i);
    else
        do_something_with_float(param.f);
}
```

Comment: unfortunately I can't change the function. It is a member of a class that is part of a framework used for physics research. I tried doing if statements for assigning a reference to the part of the data structure I'm interested in. Assigning it to be an int if the part of the data was an int and similarly for a float. Then calling the member of that specialized class to use either the int or the float depending on which should be used (I know this isn't very clear but I'm not sure of a better way of explaining it)

Comment: @user1642466, so that function has a fixed semantics. Does _it_ distinguish between `int` and `float`? If not, why do _you_? If so, what mechanism does it provide for distinguishing them? Or are you trying to call two different functions based on whether the number is `int` or `float`? If so, the same answer here applies.

Comment: it does distinguish between an int and a float. if it means anything to you I am using the ROOT analysis framework that is used by CERN for physics research. I am specifically using their TH1D histogram class. I have tried some stupid and simple methods of fixing this problem (doing if statements that direct the script to go to a function that deals with ints or an almost identical function that goes to one that deals with floats but It claimed that the histograms were not being filled with data as expected)

Comment: I don't know any of those, but the if statement should have done the trick. Maybe the problem is somewhere else.

Comment: I appreciate the help and I figure the problem is somewhere else. This framework for me has been a bit quirky in the way that it handles some code. I guess I'll just keep the two separate for now and change the type of variable manually as needed. If I really need it in the future I may ask the ROOT forum and see what they have to say.

Answer (score 2):

**Don't use a `union`.**

Make that variable a `double` in all cases.

A typical 64-bit `double` can represent all 32-bit `int` values exactly.

Remember Donald Knuth’s adage, “premature optimization is the root of all evil”

Also, remember Alexandrescu & Sutter, “don’t sweat the small stuff!“.

Also, remember the KISS principle, “Keep It Simple, Stupid”.

And before Reddit crowd starts downvoting on account of perceived negativity in answer, I should better link to an encyclopedia saying about the same, hey, [KISS in Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle).

Comment: @Shahbaz: I didn't say that. It's not complicated. Like the `goto`, it's utterly simple. Think about the last time you heard someone advocating `goto`. No, does not ring any bell? Well, in that case, think about why. It does not have to do with complexity or simplicity of `goto` itself. Rather, for `goto` it has to do with *degrees of freedom*, that the statement is too unrestricted, providing the programmer with an exponential in number of statements ways to foul up. OK? So, now think about `union`.

Comment: Even though `goto` is actually pretty common for error handling in C, let's not go there. Regarding our own scenario, using a `union` answers the question more generally. If you have two types, whatever they may be, you can union them. Your solution is good only and only for this specific purpose.

Comment: Also, in this specific case, storing values in double means double storage compared to union. Probably not crucial to the OP's application, but could certainly bring a video game to its knees.

Comment: @Shahbas: ignoring your evaluation, you're wrong about the facts. the `union` uses the same size as the largest member, plus padding (if any). check it.

Comment: Both `int` and `float` are 4 bytes. Check it ;)

Comment: @Shahbaz could you indicate in which part of the standard is that specified?

Comment: So why are you advocating against using `union`? I don't see anything in your answer that addresses *that* simple question. And your link to KISS in Wikipedia makes your answer deserve a downvote on that alone. Telling someone to keep it simple is just stupid. Tell us why is it better not to use `union`?

Comment: @Shahbaz: you're still wrong. you have a `union` of `int` and `float`, that's 4 bytes on a 32-bit system. plus a `bool` to keep track of the dynamic type of the `union`, and in practice, while the `bool` itself is typically just 1 byte, it typically takes up 4 bytes when passed on the stack, and in some other contexts. Plus that handling these will probably tend to be slower than handling a single `double`. It is certainly more code. So, in conclusion, you're wrong.

Comment: I advocate using `goto` all the time in C (but not in C++).  However, I wouldn't really recommend using `union` in C++ either; it's not a truly general solution there either (unions can store only POD types). I think `boost::variant` is the way to go if you want something general.

Comment: @jamesdlin, how is C different from C++ in matter of `goto`? I can't see any difference, both of the languages provide exactly same control statements.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf: I never said the KISS principle was dumb, I said it was dumb to provide a link to a description of that principal rather than actually saying why a `union` is more complex.

Comment: @Jonathatan: please forgive my misunderstanding. i didn't realize that you *had not read* my answer about that, which is *my first comment*. please do read, and please do consult other sources (I wholeheartedly recommend a few good textbooks on programming, because you can't really learn programming via comments on Stack Overflow).'

Comment: @griwes, because then you can jump over constructors of some variables for the least part. Besides, the mentality of C++ is to code at a higher level than in C.

Comment: @mfontanini, good question! I'm looking at the C11 standard and I can't seem to find anything regarding the width of the integer types. Even the fact that `char` is 1 byte (which everyone insists on). [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_data_types#Basic_types) says it can be anything >= 8. In practice however, `int` is set to 32 bits for legacy code and `long int` to the word size of the CPU. The floating points also ubiquitously follow IEEE 754, so `float` is also 32 bits. The standard of course leaves these widths open.

Comment: @Shahbaz: the minimum widths of the integer types are specified by the C standard, which is referenced by the C++ standard.

Comment: @Griwes: In C++, you use RAII to manage resources automatically.  In C, the sane way to manage resources in the face of failure is to follow a SESE (single entry, single exit) idiom with `goto`.  Furthermore, `goto` in C++ makes construction/destruction of automatic objects a little weird.

Answer (score 1):

Use a union. It feels kind of like a struct but it only holds one of the members. See, for example: http://www.go4expert.com/forums/showthread.php?t=15.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a complex alternative:

```
class Base { virtual ~Base() { } };
class Int : public Base { int a; };
class Float : public Base { float a; };
class Both {
public:
   Base &choose(int i) { 
     switch(i) {
     case 0: return my_int;
     case 1: return my_float;
     };
   }
private:
   Int my_int;
   Float my_float;
};
```

Then it's either virtual functions or dynamic_cast to do anything with Base references.

Addtional good trick is to add conversions between them:

```
void calc_int() {
  my_int.a = (int)my_float.a;
}
void calc_float() {
  my_float.a = (float)my_int.a;
}
```

And then it's just matter of setters:

```
void set(int a) {
  my_int.a = a;
  calc_float();
}
void set(float a) {
  my_float.a = a;
  calc_int();
}
```

Comment: so with this I could have "a" as my variable and switch it to be declared as either an int or a float depending on which I need?